# How I can start multiple download async in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

my problem is the following: I just want to run x requests at the same time depending on the user.

Well, it seems to work fine when the MaxConcurrentDownloads variable is equal to 1, but when I increase it, say 10: I have to wait for the 10taches to finish for it to execute so that Console.WriteLine as to write, when it's supposed to run asynchronously, right?

Can you help me? Here is a minimalist version of my "problem" (Also I want to specify that I have no compiler or syntax errors)

main.c

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test_client
{
    class Program
    {
        private static client cli = new client();

        private static readonly string PATH = @Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        private static int concurrency = 100;

        private static async Task<bool> MakeJOB(int pos)
        {
            return await cli.NewRequest<bool>((HttpClient client)=>
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpClientHandler handler = null;
                    if (cli.handler != null)
                        handler = cli.GethandlerIndexed(pos);
                    client = new HttpClient(handler);

                    cli.AssignDefaultHeaders(client);

                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://api.my-ip.io/ip.txt").Result)
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        Console.WriteLine(content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result + " / " + Task.CurrentId);
                    return true;
                }
                catch { /* exception .. */ return false; }
            });
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            cli.SetConcurrentDownloads(concurrency);

            var t = new Task[concurrency];
            int pos = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++, pos++)
                t[i] = MakeJOB(pos++);
            await Task.WhenAll(t);
        }
    }
}
```

client.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace test_client
{
    public class client
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpClient> Clients;
        public SemaphoreSlim Locker;
        private CancellationTokenSource TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public HttpClientHandler[] handler { get; set; }
        public string[] address { get; set; }
        public string[] port { get; set; }
        public string[] username { get; set; }
        public string[] password { get; set; }
        public int MaxConcurrentDownloads { get; set; }

        private void initializeHandler(string address = "", string port = "", string user = "", string pass = "")
        {
            initializeHandler(new string[] { string.Concat(address, ":", port, ":", user, ":", pass) });
        }

        private void initializeHandler(string[] proxies_client)
        {
            if (proxies_client == null || proxies_client.Length == 0)
                return;

            this.address = new string[proxies_client.Length];
            this.port = new string[proxies_client.Length];
            this.username = new string[proxies_client.Length];
            this.password = new string[proxies_client.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < proxies_client.Length; i++)
            {
                var split = proxies_client[i].Split(new char[] { ':' });

                this.address[i] = split[0] != "" ? split[0] : "";
                this.port[i] = split[1] != "" ? split[1] : "";
                this.username[i] = split[2] != "" ? split[2] : "";
                this.password[i] = split[3] != "" ? split[3] : "";
            }

            var proxies = new WebProxy[proxies_client.Length];
            NetworkCredential[] credential = new NetworkCredential[proxies_client.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < proxies_client.Length; i++)
            {
                if (this.username[i] != "")
                    credential[i] = new NetworkCredential(this.username[i], this.password[i]);
                else
                    credential[i] = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            }

            const string protocol = "http://";
            for (int i = 0; i < proxies.Length; i++)
            {
                if (this.address[i] != "")
                {
                    var uri = proxies_client[i].Split(new char[] { ':' });
                    if (!uri[0].Contains(protocol))
                        uri[0] = string.Concat(protocol, uri[0]);
                    proxies[i] = new WebProxy()
                    {
                        Address = new Uri(string.Concat(uri[0], ":", uri[1])),
                        Credentials = credential[i],
                    };
                }
            };

            this.handler = new HttpClientHandler[proxies.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < proxies.Length; i++)
            {
                if (proxies[i].Address.AbsoluteUri != "")
                    this.handler[i] = new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = proxies[i] };
                else
                    this.handler[i] = new HttpClientHandler();
            }
        }

        public HttpClientHandler GethandlerIndexed(int index)
        {
            return (this.handler[index % this.handler.Length]);
        }

        public void SetConcurrentDownloads(int nb = 1)
        {
            Locker = new SemaphoreSlim(nb, nb);
        }
        public client(string[] proxies = null)
        {
            Clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpClient>();

            if (Locker is null)
                Locker = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
            if (proxies != null)
                initializeHandler(proxies);
        }

        private async Task<HttpClient> CreateClient(string Name, bool persistent, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (Clients.ContainsKey(Name))
                return Clients[Name];

            HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();

            if (persistent)
            {
                while (Clients.TryAdd(Name, newClient) is false)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    await Task.Delay(1, token);
                }
            }

            return newClient;
        }

        public async Task<T> NewRequest<T>(Func<HttpClient, T> Expression, int? MaxTimeout = 2000, string Id = null)
        {
            await Locker.WaitAsync(MaxTimeout ?? 2000, TokenSource.Token);

            bool persistent = true;
            if (Id is null)
            {
                persistent = false;
                Id = string.Empty;
            }

            try
            {
                HttpClient client = await CreateClient(Id, persistent, TokenSource.Token);
                T result = await Task.Run<T>(() => Expression(client), TokenSource.Token);

                if (persistent is false)
                    client?.Dispose();

                return result;
            }
            finally
            {
                Locker.Release();
            }
        }

        public void AssignDefaultHeaders(HttpClient client)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36");
            //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        }

        public async Task Cancel(string Name)
        {
            if (Clients.ContainsKey(Name))
            {
                CancellationToken token = TokenSource.Token;
                HttpClient foundClient;

                while (Clients.TryGetValue(Name, out foundClient) is false)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    await Task.Delay(1, token);
                }

                if (foundClient != null)
                {
                    foundClient?.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        public void ForceCancelAll()
        {
            TokenSource?.Cancel();
            TokenSource?.Dispose();
            TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            foreach (var item in Clients)
            {
                item.Value?.Dispose();
            }

            Clients.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, if you're accessing the `.Result` property of a task, you're doing something wrong. You should `await` tasks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I spotted in a quick skim: Your line in `main.cs::Program.MakeJOB`:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://api.my-ip.io/ip.txt").Result)
```

should instead read

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.my-ip.io/ip.txt"))
```

This may not be your only issue, but by not awaiting the GetAsync method, you are effectively blocking on the request rather than yielding control back to the caller so that it can, for instance, context switch between tasks or queue up other tasks.

Same goes for

```
Console.WriteLine(content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result + " / " + Task.CurrentId);
```

which should be

```
Console.WriteLine((await content.ReadAsStringAsync()) + " / " + Task.CurrentId);
```

Although that one is not likely to block for a significant amount of time.

Comment: Hey, I tried this it stil not working ..